# How to get previous days date in kshell

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ksh, aix

I have a command which gives previous days date:

```
date -d '-1 day' '+%Y%d%m'
```

Same command is giving error when run in AIX system.

"-d is not recognized flag"

Below command is working which gives present date AIX system.

```
date -u +%Y%d%m
```

but below command giving error as "1 is not recognized flag"

```
date -u '-1 day' +%Y%d%m
```

How to get previous days date in AIX.

Comment: What is the error? The command works fine on my system, with `ksh --version` giving `sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01`

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: The behaviour of `date` is determined by the platform, not the shell, unless your platform has the full ast-open suite with ksh builtin equivalents for many unix utilities.

Answer (score 1):

`date` is a program, and not a builtin command of shell. So it should work regardless of the shell used.

```
falsetru@ubuntu:~$ bash
falsetru@ubuntu:~$ date -d '-1 day' '+%Y%d%m'
20142103
falsetru@ubuntu:~$ ksh
$ date -d '-1 day' '+%Y%d%m'
20142103
$ type date
date is a tracked alias for /bin/date
```

Comment: Hi, My system is AIX. And it is giving error as not recognized flag: d

Comment: @user3164140, Try `type date` or `which date` in both bash and ksh. Compare the result.

Answer (score 1):

Manipulating the Timezone is possible for changing the clock some hours.
An extra complexity is the Daylight Saving Time. Due to the daylight saving time, 24 hours ago can be today or the day before yesterday.

You are sure that yesterday is 20 or 30 hours ago. Which one? Well, the most recent one that is not today.

```
echo "$(TZ=GMT+30 date +%Y-%m-%d)\n$(TZ=GMT+20 date +%Y-%m-%d)" | grep -v $(date +%Y-%m-%d) | tail -1
```

Above command is for ksh. When you use bash, you want echo -e:

```
echo -e "$(TZ=GMT+30 date +%Y-%m-%d)\n$(TZ=GMT+20 date +%Y-%m-%d)" | grep -v $(date +%Y-%m-%d) | tail -1
```

Answer (score 0):

`date -d` is a `GNU`ism and thus is not available in non-`GNU` implementations like the vanilla `AIX` `date`. You can, however, install `coreutils` (download link [here](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/ezinstall.html)) on `AIX` which ships with `GNU date`.